# Passing Array to PHP from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to pass my JS array to PHP array and all of the solutions that I have found here is useless or I can integrate these solutions to my problem.

**Javascript**

```
$('#siparisButon').click(function(){
                 var splitListe = $('#siparis-block span').text();
                 splitListe = splitListe.split("- ");
                 splitListe = JSON.stringify(splitListe);
                 $.post("menu.php",{'siparisListe[]': splitListe});
                 // I have a div that shows the result of PHP function and it says undefined index.
                 $('#fonksiyon').show();
          })
```

**PHP**

```
function ekleme(){
          if($_POST['siparisListe']){
                 $liste = $_POST['siparisListe'];
                 echo $liste;
          }
   }
```

Comment: JSON encode the array: `echo json_encode($liste);`. You'll also need to include a callback function on the `$.post` call to receive the data you output from PHP. Check the documentation for an example of how this is supposed to work: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post

Comment: if you're PHP doesn't require an array, perhaps pass the string to the PHP and split it then .

Comment: `siparisListe[]` is the property name constructor for the `input`, you would refer to it as `$_POST['siparisListe']` and expect that to be an array. Remove the `[]` from `$.post()`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
$('#siparisButon').click(function(){
     var splitListe = $('#siparis-block span').text();
     splitListe = splitListe.split("- ");
     splitListe = JSON.stringify(splitListe);
     $.post("menu.php",{'siparisListe[]': splitListe});
     // I have a div that shows the result of PHP function and it says undefined index.
     $('#fonksiyon').show();
})
```

modify you code in to this

```
$('#siparisButon').click(function(){
     var splitListe = $('#siparis-block span').text();
     splitListe = splitListe.split("- ");

     var input_data = new FormData();
     $.each(splitListe,function(index,value){
         input_data.append("siparisListe["+index+"]",value)
     });
     $.ajax({
        url: "menu.php",
        data: input_data,
        type: "POST",
          success: function(data) {
            $("#passwordMatch").html(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {}
     })

     // I have a div that shows the result of PHP function and it says undefined index.
     $('#fonksiyon').show();
})
```

Comment: On console, your code gives **TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.**

Comment: There's no Form object on my page, I'm just trying to pass list that I get from a div's text.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `[]` from the `POST` field name and pass it an array (jQuery will `JSON` encode it for you).

```
$('#siparisButon').click(function() {
     let splitListe = ($('#siparis-block span').text() || '').split('- ');

     if (splitListe) {
         $.post("menu.php", { siparisListe: splitListe });

         $('#fonksiyon').show();
     }
});
```

Then in your PHP to verify:

```
function ekleme() {
    if ($liste = $_POST['siparisListe']) {
         var_dump($liste);
    }

    echo 'No $liste array in POST.';
}
```

Comment: It still says undefined index